# Any boot system to drain a computer battery?

Tags: battery

When receiving a laptop replacement **battery**, one need to **calibrate** it, which mean fully charging it, and **draining it to a residual charge of about 3%**.

I want to **accelerate the battery discharge stage** without having to interact with the computer, nor having to log in (e.g. for laptops from clients).

Hence, I'm looking for a **bootable operating system** (preferably a live USB, or alteratively a live CD) to generate "random" action (possibly CPU and GPU intensive) **to discharge the battery faster**.

Alternatively, a CPU-/GPU- intensive command that I could run in the terminal of a boot CD could do the job would be appreciated.

If the live USB drive or CD is able **shutdown the computer automatically when the remaining charge reaches 3%**, it would be appreciated ; else I could use some Linux command.

The computer and screen must not go to sleep if not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a linux bootable usb key.

Next you can use the command yes to make run your cpu.
If you want to go faster you can use stress test software like Stress-ng.
To finish you can make work you computer like mining crypto or bruteforcing some password.

Comment: Thank you for the good ideas.